# Open Daylight can not login and the ui of the web always display "unable to login"

Tags: authentication, opendaylight

I have install the Open Daylight Helium according to the document of wiki of installation. But, when I enable the webUI, it always displays "Unable to login" in the webUI.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This   would be  easier  to answer  if you  described  what  you  mean by the  web UI.  Nonetheless vaerify that  you  are testing the  correctports, if  you are  then you  can disable auth by editing org.opendaylight.aaa.authn.cfg

> authEnabled=false

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, we need to install feature of odl-dlux-core. And we can login to ODL's Web GUI successfully.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I got it working by following the answer on this link:
https://ask.opendaylight.org/question/843/unable-to-login-dlux-web-interface-helium-release/

There it says:

> - Downloading and extracting the pre-build .zip : distribution-karaf-0.2.0-Helium.zip
> - ./distribution-karaf-0.2.0-Helium/bin/karaf (on linux) to start the karaf container
> - feature:install odl-restconf odl-l2switch-switch odl-mdsal-apidocs odl-dlux-core
> - Accessing http://localhost:8181/dlux/index.html where localhost is your local ip
> - log in with user: admin pw: admin
>
> Perhaps there is a problem with the order you have installed your features. I >got the order from dlux-wiki-page where they said that this is the recommended >way of installing features before starting the dlux feature.
>
> To clean your local karaf container you can start the container using the clean >flag like "./distribution-karaf-0.2.0-Helium/bin/karaf clean" or delete the >"distribution-karaf-0.2.0-Helium/data/" folder.